# Efficient evaluation of $\sinh(15),~\sinh(0.001)$ (floating point arithmetic)

Tags: numerical-methods, floating-point

In floating point arithmetic, compute efficiently: $$\sinh x=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$
for $x=15,~x=-15,~x=0.001$.

**Attempt.** For $x=15$ we compute $e^{15}$ as a finite sum $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{k}\frac{15^n}{n!}$ for $k$ large enough and $e^{-15}=1/e^{15}.$

For $x=-15$, $\sinh(-15)=-\sinh (15)$ and for $x=0.001$ we evaluate $\sinh 0.001$ as a finite sum $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{k}\frac{0.001^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$ for $k$ large enough (depending on the given precision).

Am I on the right path?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yeah, except you might want to be careful with the floating point.  It'll put a dent in your calculations.

Comment: $e^{-15}$ might as well be $0$ compare to $e^{15}$...

Comment: For large positive $x$, a common speed up is treat $e^x$ as $(e^{x/2^n})^{2^n}$ for suitable $n$, approximate $e^{x/2^n}$ by its Taylor expansion and then repeat squaring....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can
manipulate the bits
of a floating point number,
you can use
$e^x
=2^{x/\ln 2}
=2^{\lfloor x/\ln 2 \rfloor +\{x/\ln 2\}}
=2^{\lfloor x/\ln 2 \rfloor} 2^{\{x/\ln 2\}}
$
where
$\{ z \}$
is the fractional part of $z$.

$2^{\lfloor x/\ln 2 \rfloor}$
can be gotten by creating
the correct exponent bits
in a floating point number
(with fractional part
representing $1$ or
$\frac12$ depending 
on the format)
and
$2^{\{x/\ln 2\}}
=e^{\ln 2\{x/\ln 2\}}
$
can be computed by
the power series for
$e^z$
with a small argument
$(0 \le\ln 2\{x/\ln 2\} < 1)$
which converges quickly.

This works for
negative $x$ as well as positive.

For your case,
I would compute
$\sinh(x)
=\dfrac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}
=\dfrac{e^x}{2}-\dfrac{e^{-x}}{2}
=\dfrac{e^x}{2}-\dfrac{1}{2e^x}
$.

Note that if
$e^{2x} > 2^{m+1}$,
where $m$ is the
number of bits
in the floating point
fraction part,
then
only $e^x$ needs to be computed.

Also note that
if $|x|$ is small,
$e^x \approx 1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}
$
so
$\sinh(x) \approx x+\frac{x^3}{6}
$.
The values of $x$
for which this is useful
depends on the accuracy needed.